# Render child components with react-native-router

Tags: react-native

I am deploying a React Native application, using [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux).

Therefore, I have defined the nested routes in the *root* application file as below:

```
export default class Dashboard extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Scene key="root">
          <Scene key="app" component={App} title='App'>
            <Scene key="application_dashboard" component={ApplicationLauncher} title="Dashboard"/>
            <Scene key="example_interactions" component={ExampleInteractions} title="ExampleInteractions" initial={true} />
          </Scene>
        </Scene>
      </Router>
      )
  }
}
```

**ExampleInteractions component**, which is supposed to be initially loaded, just renders a long text:

```
export default class ExampleInteractions extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>.....long text.....</Text>
      </View>
      );
  }
}
```

---

### Goal

Render any of the *child* components (ApplicationLauncher, ExampleInteractions) within the `Content` tags in App component.

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppContainer>
        <ColleagueHeader/>  
        <ScrollableContainer>
          <BaseHeader/>
          <CustomerHeader/>      
          <Content>
            ****** I would like to render the child component here *****
          </Content>
          <Footer/>
        </ScrollableContainer>
      </AppContainer>

      );
  }
}
```

Approaches tried:

### 1) {this.props.children}

```
<Content>
{this.props.children}                
</Content>
```

But it fails under the following error:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {key, name, sceneKey, parent, type, title, initial, component, index}).

And `{this.props.children}` Object is:
[image: this.props.children output]

### 2) {this.props.children[0].component}

```
<Content>
{this.props.children[0].component}
</Content>
```

And then, the base `App` component renders properly, but the children component `ExampleInteractions` doesn't. Therefore, `Content` is empty.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you try the following :

```
<Content>
  {React.createElement(this.props.children[0].component, {key: "you can pass props here"})}
</Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this same question.

I know that to display a single component you can do the following and it will display the first sub-scene.

```
import { DefaultRenderer } from 'react-native=router-flux';

<Content>
   <DefaultRenderer 
      navigationState={this.props.children[0]} 
      onNavigate={this.props.onNavigate} 
   />
</Content>
```

The RNRF docs don't directly address how DefaultRenderer works, I just tried it out after finding it written somewhere in an example (can't find it any longer).

I'm still working on the issue of actually navigating between the sub-scenes. I'll update if I can figure it out.